# Pronunciation of "Rock" and "Ruck"

Tags: pronunciation

Guten Tag, all. I was looking words up on [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc) just now, and I realized how the two German words *[Rock](http://www.dict.cc/?s=Rock)* and *[Ruck](http://www.dict.cc/?s=Ruck)* sound exactly identical – at least to my ears, with headphones on – as I clicked on the *Voice Output* panel and listened to the audio pronunciation by native German speakers.

I had always thought that the *u* in *Ruck* was supposed to pronounced like we would in *ruby* (English), but on dict.cc, every native speaker of German recorded differently.

Is my hearing playing a trick on me, or are they really pronounced the same? I honestly doubt that the latter would be true, though.

Comment: Rock is like "rocky", RUck is like "Rookie", just shorter

Comment: Jetzt verstehe ich. Vielen Dank, alle!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, they aren't. The former is [ʀɔk](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/df/De-Rock.ogg), the latter [ʀʊk] (compare the *dirkausob*'s recording there in [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=ruck)).

Comment: Yes, that is how I had perceived them until I ran into the pronunciations on dict.cc. I can see your point, which makes sense. I guess what caused the confusion was that the difference between the two pronunciations was too subtle for me to tell. Does a native speaker give care to such delicate details when he/she is having an everyday conversation?

Comment: @T.G.Monk, to a native speaker the distinction between *Rock* and *Ruck* is not at all subtle.

Answer (score 3):

It is interesting that the pronunciation examples sound the same to you. To me as a native German speaker they are easily distinguishable. I find the pronunciations of *Rock* and *Ruck* by user patu on dict.cc very good.

Actually, the *u* in *Ruck* is not as in *ruby*, but as in [*hook*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-close_near-back_rounded_vowel).

Comment: I have made another recording. It is temporarily [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e3vtdztzn0qyniv/RockRuck.m4a). If someone tells me a good place for a permanent upload, I can add it to the answer.

Comment: I can see the distinction clearly now.

Thank you so much for the audio, Carsten. It was very helpful. The distinction stood out instantly when the two were pronounced alternately.

I guess what gave me trouble was the sound quality on dict.cc. Still, it's a wonderful utility website.

Comment: @T.G.Monk, I am glad that I could help.

Answer (score 2):

"Rock" is pronounced as in "Rock & Roll". "Ruck" is pronounced more like saying "rook" in English with a short "oo" (or as Carsten Schultz so rightly noted: like the *oo* in *hook*).

Comment: Ha, until now I mispronounced *rook*, I thought it had a long vowel.